# What should we do with floor tiles that were applied with Type 1 Mapei mastic?

Tags: bathroom, tile, floor, ceramic-tile, troubleshooting

We tiled a 25 sq. ft bathroom with 12X12 porcelain tiles. Instead of a bag of normal powered mortar (which covered more area than we needed), we picked up the tub of [Type 1 Mapei](http://www.mapei.com/US-EN/Tile-&-Stone-Installation-Systems/Mastics/Type-1) and were told it was okay to use too. We thought it was just a premixed version of the normal stuff. After the tiles were laid we learned it should not be used for 12X12 *floor* tiles, only 12X12 wall tiles.

We tried to see if we could remove the tiles, but it had already been 24 hours and they wouldn't come up. This is the second day. We have not grouted yet.

Should we try harder to remove the tiles? *We do not want to take the chance of them breaking.* OR Should we grout and hope for the best and deal with any breakage when or if it comes? Or does anyone have another suggestion?

Comment: I'd say you're likely to crack quite a few tiles if you try to pull them up. Better to replace them individually if needed on down the road, rather than risk cracking a bunch now, just because they MIGHT crack later.

Comment: I am currently in the exact same situation. Installed 2” circle tiles with type1 on the shower floor. 

How has your experience been? Any words of caution for me? I’ve been scouring the internet for what the possible effects are other than “not manufacturer recommended”

Answer (score 7):

What's done is done. I'd grout and generally move on with life, and only revisit it if and when the tiles start popping on their own, which may never happen.

You are NOT a professional tile installer who would be well advised to rip out and do it over for the sake of their reputation. So you don't need to act like one.

Comment: When/if the tiles start popping, they'll probably chip the tub and possibly break on impact. Personally, I'd wet the edges and try to pry them off, but that's because I don't like rolling the dice on this sort of thing.

Comment: @User95050: unless gravity suddenly goes out of whack, floor tiles cannot possibly fall on the tub.

Comment: Straight to remedial reading for me... I somehow understood them to be wall tiles. Given all that, I totally wouldn't worry about them.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It does ease my mind a little that no one said these tiles are sure to crack or they've had to repair floors from this newbie DIYer error many times before.
Since the bathroom is small at least if any do crack there won't be many to replace. We now know to read the packaging more carefully and a quick search for YouTube videos might help.

Comment: I also vote for leave it and see. It doesn't take much to hold tiles down. If they popped that easily, almost nobody would be able to tile. I looked at a spec sheet for Type 1 Mapei  and I didn't see anything about not using on floor tiles that are 12x12.